# XStream deserializing simple XML keeps giving error saying no such field when it should be creating a collection

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, deserialization, xstream

Trying to convert the following xml to java objects...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layertypes>
  <layertype id="layer_1" label="first" />
  <layertype id="layer_2" label="Second" />
</layertypes>
```

with these classes:

```
@XStreamAlias("layertype")
public class LayerType {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String id;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String label;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

and

```
@XStreamAlias("layertypes")
public class LayerTypes {

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "layertype")
    private List<LayerType> layertypes = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<LayerType> getLayertypes() {
        return layertypes;
    }
    public void setLayertypes(List<LayerType> layertypes) {
        this.layertypes = layertypes;
    }
}
```

and these classes and xstream are called from here:

```
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.processAnnotations(LayerType.class);
        xstream.processAnnotations(LayerTypes.class);
        LayerTypes layerTypes = (LayerTypes) xstream.fromXML(inputStream);
```

and I get this:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field xbeans.LayerTypes.layertype
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No such field  xbeans.LayerTypes.layertype
field               : layertype
class               : xbeans.LayerTypes
required-type       : xbeans.LayerTypes
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /layertypes/layertype
line number         : 3
version             : 1.4.15
-------------------------------
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?   Stepping through the debugger it's like Xstream just can't find or doesn't have a mapper for the implicit collection.   This seems like it should be so simple and I've tried following all the tutorials I've found.  Yet always this error.

Comment: I wrote a simple unit test to exercise the code in relative "isolation" it runs as expected.  However when running inside the spring boot application I get the error mentioned above.  I'm honestly baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I wasn't doing anything wrong.   Some how Spring Boot Dev Tools was breaking it.
[Error using XStream in Spring context: DuplicateFieldException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176413/error-using-xstream-in-spring-context-duplicatefieldexception)

Similar issue different exception (though both exceptions are irrelevant and misleading).